# Would async/await provide benefit over Task for intertwined statements?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a method (called via an AJAX request) that runs at the end of a sequence. In this method I save to the database, send emails, look up a bunch of info in other APIs/databases, correlate things together, etc.. I just refactored the original method into a second revision and used `Task`s to make it asynchronous, and shaved off up to two seconds in wall time. I used `Task`s mainly because it seemed easier (I'm not that experienced in async/await yet) and some tasks depend on other tasks (like task C D and E all depend on results from B, which itself depends on A). Basicalll all of the tasks are started at the same time (processing just zips down the to the `Wait()` call on the email task, which in one way or another requires all the others to complete. I generally do something like this except with something like eight tasks:

```
public thing() {
    var FooTask<x> = Task<x>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        // ...
        return x;
    });
    var BarTask<y> = Task<y>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      // ...
      var y = FooTask.Result;
      // ...
      return y + n;
    }
    var BazTask<z> = Task<z>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      var y = FooTask.Result;
      return y - n;
    }
    var BagTask<z> = Task<z>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      var g = BarTask.Result;
      var h = BazTask.Result;
      return 1;
    }
    // Lots of try/catch aggregate shenanigans.
    BagTask.Wait();
    return "yay";
}
```

Oh I also need to roll back previous things if something breaks, like remove a database row if the email fails to send, so there are a few levels of try/catches in there. Anyway, all of this works (amazingly, it all worked on the first try). My question is whether this sort of method would benefit from being rewritten to use async/await rather than `Task`s. If so, how would the multiple-dependency scenario play out without re-running an async method that was already ran or awaited by another method? I guess some shared variable?

**Update:**

The `// ...` lines were supposed to indicate that the task was doing something, like looking up DB records. Sorry if that wasn't clear. About half of the tasks (there are 8 total) can take up to maybe five seconds to run, if the contexts aren't warmed up, and the other half of the tasks just collect/assemble/process/use that data.

Comment: Actually I think that [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be a better fit for this. Also see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html

Comment: None of this is asynchronous.  You're doing everything *synchronously* by constantly blocking on each of the tasks.  That said, if you had actually implemented it properly using `Task`s without `await` then using `await` would only be an arguably simpler way of writing it; it wouldn't be functionally different.

Comment: When I watch the logs and debug it, it sure seems asynchronous up until the final block (or partially up to the intermediate blocks).

Comment: @Josh You're asynchronously starting a bunch of tasks that all start immediately and then block, synchronously, until the previous task(s) have finished, and then you synchronously block until the final task has finished.    None of these tasks should be synchronously blocking on others, and you shouldn't be synchronously blocking on the final task.

Comment: Exactly, they all start immediately and do some stuff. That's the asynchronous part. I need to know everything finished and handle exceptions, which is why I block at the end before returning the appropriate response.

Comment: @Josh They all start immediately and then sit there doing nothing until the previous task has finished.  They should instead not be started until the previous tasks have actually completed; that would be a proper asynchronous implementation.  If you want this to actually be an asynchronous implementation, then it's important that you not be blocking on any tasks ever, rather than blocking on every single task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also need to roll back previous things if something breaks, like remove a database row if the email fails to send, so there are a few levels of try/catches in there.

You'll find that `async`/`await` (paired with `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`) will make your code much cleaner:

```
var x = await Task.Run(() => {
  ...
  return ...;
});
var y = await Task.Run(() => {
  ...
  return x + n;
});
var bazTask = Task.Run(() => {
  ...
  return y - n;
});
var bagTask = Task.Run(async () => {
  ...
  var g = y;
  var h = await bazTask;
  return 1;
}
await bagTask;
return "yay";
```

You also have the option of using `Task.WhenAll` if you want to `await` multiple tasks completing. Error handling in particular is cleaner with `await` since it doesn't wrap exception in `AggregateException`.

**However**

> called via an AJAX request

This is a bit of a problem. Both `StartNew` and `Task.Run` should be avoided on ASP.NET.

> shaved off up to two seconds in wall time

Yes, parallel processing on ASP.NET (which is what the code is currently doing) will make *individual* requests execute faster, but **at the expense of scalability**. The server will be unable to handle as many requests if it is doing parallel processing on each one.

> save to the database, send emails, look up a bunch of info in other APIs/databases

These are all I/O-bound operations, not CPU-bound. So the **ideal** solution is to create truly-async I/O methods and then just call them using `await` (and `Task.WhenAll` if necessary). By "truly-async", I mean calling the underlying asynchronous APIs (e.g., `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` instead of `WebClient.DownloadString`; or Entity Framework's `ToListAsync` instead of `ToList`, etc). Using `StartNew` or `Task.Run` is what I call "fake asynchrony".

Once you have asynchronous APIs, your top-level method really becomes simple:

```
X x = await databaseService.GetXFromDatabaseAsync();
Y y = await apiService.LookupValueAsync(x);
Task<Baz> bazTask = databaseSerivce.GetBazFromDatabaseAsync(y);
Task<Bag> bagTask = apiService.SecondaryLookupAsync(y);
await Task.WhenAll(bazTask, bagTask);
Baz baz = await bazTask;
Bag bag = await bagTask;
return baz + bag;
```

Comment: So the async/await approach "moves" the work out of asp.net so that it can handle more requests, and there is some sort of technical or practical limit within IIS (or the app pool or something) that limits how many tasks/threads it can handle?

Comment: @Josh: Sort of. `async`/`await` embraces the naturally-threadless way that asynchronous operations work. So it's not really moving the work out; it's just not blocking threads unnecessarily like `Task.Result` would do. If the "threadless" comment is confusing, I have a blog post [explaining how there is no thread for truly asynchronous I/O](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: Actually after reading & thinking on your answer, I re-read (for like the sixth time) the [async article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and caught a couple words I didn't fully comprehend before: the await keyword yields control to the _caller of the method that calls await_ (until the await is ready), and _await creates a continuation_ for the remainder of its method's work before yielding, to continue later. These seem obvious now, but thanks for steering my mind in the right direction on that.

Comment: @Josh: I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find helpful.